# Не срабатывают точки останова в CLion

Tags: c++, отладка, clion

Установил IDE CLion, не могу разобраться с отладкой. Ставлю точки останова, нажимаю дебаг, программа отрабатывает, вылезает консоль с результатом, закрывается, в консоли CLion - "Process finished with exit code 0". В окне отладки сообщение:

[image: Окно отладки].

Настройки выглядят так:
[image: Настройки]

Код:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
void f(int m[5]) { 
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) { 
        m[i] *= 2; m++; 
        } 
} 
int main() { 
    int a[5] = {1,1,1,1,1}; 
    f(a); 
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) 
        printf("%d ", a[i]); return 0; 
    }
}
```

С классическим "Хелло" то же самое. Программу с флагом `-g` не компилировал. VS 2015 дебажит этот код, PyCharm дебажит (от CLion я ожидал похожей работы отладчика). Видится мне что я накосячил с какими-то компонентами или настройками. MinGW ставил через Installation Manager. gdb и компиляторы стоят.

Comment: Когда программа завершается с нулевым кодом это означает, что в программе не было ошибок. Возможно ваша программа не исполняет тот код где указана точка останова. Было бы легче, если бы вы привели пример кода.

Comment: Создайте классический "hello world" и поставьте точку останова на main. Сработает? Нужно больше подробностей по Вашим действиям.

Comment: Вы программу скомпилировали с флагом -g?

Comment: Если `-g` не попадает в компилятор, то итоговый бинарник не содержит отладочной информации, соответственно никакие точки останова не сработают.

Comment: @alexolut набрал в консоли g++ main.cpp -g, появился файл с расширением .exe. На вкладке gdb отладчика то же самое(что на скриншоте): "No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command."

Comment: @Сергей Проверил в консоли на установленном с `Qt` `mingw`. Создал `test.cpp`, Выполнил `g++ test.cpp -g`, получил файл `a.exe`. Запустил `gdb a.exe`, увидел в том числе строку: `Reading symbols from a.exe...done.` Далее в консоли gdb установил точку останова `break main`. И сделал запуск командой `run`, получил сообщение `Breakpoint 1, main () at test.cpp:5`... т.е. никаких проблем. Может быть есть смысл переустановить `mingw`. Может с путями что, хз.

Comment: @alexolut Да, через консоль и у меня всё так! 
(gdb) break main. Breakpoint 1 at 0x401469: file main.cpp, line 13.
С путями, т.е. с переменной Path? У меня там "C:\MinGW\bin" имеется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В файле `CMakeLists.txt` своего проекта в cтроку:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

внёс флаг `-g`:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -g")
```

Теперь отладка работает.